# How to declare multiple parameters with the same data type? (java)

Tags: java, parameters, declaration

When declaring multiple variables, I can just use this syntax

```
int a, b, c;
```

But since the comma `,` is used to separate deceleration of parameters of the method, I can't use the above syntax

```
public void method (int a, int b, int c) { }
```

**So, how can I declare multiple parameters without typing the same data type multiple times?**

Comment: You can't. That's just not the way that Java parameter syntax works.

Comment: You can't. at least not in any current or proposed Java spec.

Comment: Oh OK. Thank you for the answer and the quick reply.

Comment: `public void method (int... abc)` with varargs, variable number of arguments, is another option, but not quite the same. Saving typing is not really important.

Comment: @JoopEggen , "Saving typing is not really important." that might be true, but I was wondering if there is a straight way just like the first line i posted. It's there for a reason right? As for the option you posted, I'm not familiar with. So I will look it up. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: My guess is that for method signatures the language designers wanted to prevent forgetting a type, something like `(int radius, color)`. That guess is not too far-fetched: fields have a default initialisation, local variables not. By careful consideration.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you I learned a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could try a constructor? Something like:

```
    public ExampleConstructor(int a, int b, int c)
    {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
      this.c = c;
    }
```

Then in your method just pass the constructor variables. You can use getters in your method to fetch the desired variable:

```
    public void method (ExampleConstructor eC)
    {
        whateverMethodIsDoing = eC.getA;
    }
```

This may be my first response to a question at stackOverflow, I hope it is useful.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, it's clearly not what the question was asking for :/

Comment: Hey @GuzziTony, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. It's kinda cool to be the first question to someone else. Considering I'm someone who asks a lot. Your answer is kinda cool. I didn't think about this before. Although I just wanted to use one `int` instead of 3 to save time. Would it save me much time? Probably not but if it's there then I might as well use it. Just like we use it with class variables and no one complained. Keep answering questions please, it helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

try below method.

```
  public void method(int... intVar){

      for(int num: intVar){

         System.out.println(num);

       }

   }
```

and

`method(1,2,3,4,5);`

Comment: Hey @Abdul Rafay. I'm not really sure what you did there. I will look it up but could you explain what you did in just short words? How is it possible to pass 5 arguments when you only declared one parameter?

Comment: it is called VarArgs(google it) in java. you can set varargs in your method argument type only once and pass method(1,2,3,4,5); upto many with "," separated.

Comment: Great to know. Thank you!